# Variables stored in subshell

Tags: bash

The script is reading the text from the .csv file and storing it as variables in subshell I believe, after that I want to use those variables in shell but they are blank, how to modify the script so it will always remember those variables?

```sh
INPUT=file.csv
IFS=','
while read line1
do
echo "this is $line1"
done < $INPUT

echo "test $line1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` in your script is *not* working in subshell. The variable
`line1` will be empty just after exiting the loop because `read` encounters
`end of file`, which is the condition to exit the loop. The variable `line1`
is overwritten to empty string at that moment. Please try the
following script:

```
INPUT=file.csv
IFS=','
while read -r line1
do
    echo "this is $line1"
    break
done < "$INPUT"

echo "test $line1"
```

Then you'll see the variable `$line1` holds the value of the 1st line
in the input file.
If you want to preserve the value of `$line1`, assign another variable
to it in the loop:

```
INPUT=file.csv
IFS=','
while read -r line1
do
    echo "this is $line1"
    line=$line1
done < $INPUT

echo "test1 $line1"
echo "test2 $line"
```

BTW the `IFS` will not work to split the line because you are putting just one variable. If you want to split the line into
multiple variables, please try:

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 ..
```

or

```
while IFS=, read -r -a ary
```

depending on the purpose.